# Convergence of dynamical system on the sphere

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations

Let $A(x)$ be a symmetric negative semi-definite matrix which depends continuously on the parameter $x\in\mathbb{R}^{d}$. We consider the differential equation
$$\dot{x} = (I-xx^*)A(x)x$$
on the unit sphere. Is there anything known about the convergence behaviour of the trajectories for $t\to\infty$?

If the matrix is constant it converges to a stable equilibrium.

Comment: This question is very interesting for me. Can I ask you how to prove that, if $A$ is constant, then $x(t)$ converges to a stable equilibrium? I guess that such equilibrium is related to the dominant eigenvector of $A$.

Comment: [I asked a related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3752053/8157) on Math.SE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can get any flow on the unit sphere in this way. Take $A(x)$ to be the rank-one matrix $$A(x) = -(x-b)(x^*-b^*)$$ with $b = b(x)$ tangent to the sphere (that is, orthogonal to $x$). Then $x^*b=b^*x=0$ and $x^*x = 1$, so that $$\begin{aligned}(I - xx^*)A(x)x & = xx^*(x-b)(x^*-b^*)x-(x-b)(x^*-b^*)x \\ & = x - (x-b) = b .\end{aligned}$$ Therefore, the differential equation under discussion takes form $$\dot{x} = b(x).$$

Comment: This is some how  similar to the following  fact(in the case of 2-sphere): If we  identify $S^2$  with the  space  of  projectiions  of $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ then every  vector  field  on $S^2$ can be  written in the  form $\dot X= [A,X]=AX-XA$ for some  antisymmetric  2x2 matrix A. I learned this fact in page 13 of the book Non commutative  Geometry by Alain Connes(When he  was interpreting the  consequence of  the Gauss Bonnet theorem in terms of cyclic cocycles)